# <br> tags are shown as a plain text after reloading webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I have a web page that begins with an empty div. When a user send the form with get request, the requested text is shown inside the div. The website is using Flask.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>

<body>

<form id="command-form" action="/terminal">
    <input id="command-input" name="command" type="text">
    <button id="submit-button" type="button">></button> 
 </form>

<div class="window" id="terminal-window"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()

    function send_form(e){

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#command-form").attr("action"),
            type: "get",
            caches: false,
            data: $("#command-input").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#terminal-window").html(data);    
                $("#command-input").val("");// clear input
                $("#command-input").focus();// focus input field
            }
        });
    }
    // send by submit button
    $("#submit-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        send_form(e);
    });

});
```

Sample text requested:

```
   foo
   <br>Command 'foo' is not recognised<br>
   <br>Root>
```

The requested text is pre-formatted with br tags and is displayed inside the terminal-window div.
This script is working fine. But the problem is when the page is reloaded the br tags are shown as plain text. It's not making a newline.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but the *br* tag should be self-closing like so

```
<br/>
```

Comment: But it only happens after reloading the page. A freshly opened page is working fine.

Comment: Please provide more details, as in what's the page html when you first load the page, what is it after the ajax call is completed and you fill the #terminal-window, and then, when you say refresh, do you mean manually? It's quite unclear what you're asking/doing/experiencing.

Comment: terminal-window is initially empty. The form is sent using a submit button or the enter key. Form is submitted using the ajax code included in the post. After the ajax call , server returns a txt file including the sample text. Text is preformatted with br tags. Then the success function read the text and update the div content.

Comment: Does your html include the <!DOCTYPE html> directive?

Comment: Yes. It is included